# Ordering joined data

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm

I'm currently performing the following query across 3 tables; `handset`, `deal` and `tariff`:

```
SELECT
    h.*, d.*, t.* FROM handset h
LEFT JOIN deal d ON h.id = d.handset_id
LEFT JOIN tariff t ON d.tariff_id = t.id
ORDER BY
    h.popularity
DESC LIMIT 10
```

The Tariff table has a column called `price` and I would like to join the tariff with the lowest price onto the results queried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   SELECT
   h.*, d.*, t.* FROM handset h
   LEFT JOIN deal d ON h.id = d.handset_id
   LEFT JOIN tariff t ON d.tariff_id = t.id
   where t.price=(select min(price) from tariff)
   ORDER BY
   h.popularity
   DESC LIMIT 10
```